# Selecting first element of a series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have an series object that contains multiple series (341 in this case):

[image]

I need to select only first element of each series. For example if I have series:

```
0 68 -0.22
  86 2.54
1 73 -0.10
  88 0.57
2 74 -2.18
  89 -0.10
```

I need to get something that would look like this:

```
 0 68 -0.22
 1 73 -0.10 
 2 74 -2.18
```

and so on.

For empty series I need to ger series number and Nan,or 0:

```
336 0 0
337 0 0
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what exactly do you have that holds the 341 series ? can you show this ?

Comment: Why do the rows have two values in your expected output if you want to pick just the first element from a series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is unclear. Maybe you can try:

```
out = pd.concat({x.name: x.iloc[[0]] if not x.empty
                 else pd.Series(0) for x in sr})
print(out)

# Output
0    68   -0.22
1    73   -0.10
2    74   -2.18
341  0     0.00
dtype: float64
```